# undefined variable in wordpress but it is defined

Tags: wordpress, variables, undefined

i created a wordpress theme for myself and in option panel that i get it to work with help of option tree plugin i used a category-select type to choose between.

this is a loop i wrote to choose category in my theme functions file .

```
$categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0&orderby=name');
$wp_cats = array();
foreach ($categories as $category_list ) {
$wp_cats[$category_list->cat_ID] = $category_list->cat_name;
}
array_unshift($wp_cats, "Choose A Category");
```

it's work fine on my website , but the problem is on my other website i getting error of Undefined variable

Notice: Undefined variable: wp_cats

this is a category-select array i use to call wp_cats .

```
 array(
'id'          => 'best_games_category',
'label'       => ' best games ',
'desc'        => ' desc ',
'type'        => 'category-select',
'section'     => 'category-option',
'choices'     => array( 
 array(
   'options' => $wp_cats,
   )
 )
),
```

so please tell me what is my mistake and where do i this wrong is there any problem in php version or something related to that , cuz in one site it's work fine as i mentioned but in the other it's not .

thanks in advance

Comment: which line, exactly, fails? In your example, if it's the full code, `$wp_cats` should never be undefined. Please add the full exact error message (maybe shorten the paths, but not line numbers or error message itself).

Comment: i get this error every line i used  'options' => $wp_cats, in array that i wrote above .

Comment: is this perhaps a scope problem? is `$wp_cats` defined within a function? If it is, it's only "visible" within that one function. But I'm not sure why it would work on one site but not on another.

Comment: yes it's super odd if you ask me  :D

Comment: is $wp_cats defined within a function?  = No it's not .

Comment: declare the $wp_cats as global